# Namebox from userform

Tags: vba, excel, userform, box

I have created a userform (userform6) with text boxes. I need to give a name for the last 5 rows.

Here is the code that I am using.  The code selects the last five rows as well, but got an error.

```
Dim n As Long

n = 5

Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1 - n). _
Resize(n).EntireRow.Select
Selection.Name = UserForm6.TextBox8.Text
```

I got a runtime error 1004 and error highlights "selection.name = userForm6.TextBox8.Text". I also checked the spaces, but to with no success.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try with `Selection = UserForm6.TextBox8.Text`

Comment: It replaces last five rows into textbox8.text.. But I need Name of selected Rows

Comment: Name of selected rows? What do you mean?

Comment: Might this be what you want?
`UserForm6.TextBox8.Text = Selection.Address`

Comment: @Vityata- I am thinking he is trying to name the selected range ie: `Range("A1:B1").name="MyName"` But trying to name it from a userform textbox

Answer (score 0):

You are actually looking for a `Range` - not `Cells`. Also, you don't need to `Select` it, in order to `Name` it; then why make it slower?

So here we go:

```
Dim n As Long
n = 5
Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(-n + 1).Resize(n).EntireRow.Name = UserForm6.TextBox8.Text
```

Comment: hi guys.. thank you for your help.. i managed without this... thank you